# rails ecommerce donation center

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, e-commerce, spree, donations

I am trying to create a donation centre of sorts in Rails for a non-profit, using PayPal, and am wondering if I should start from scratch or use an existing eCommerce gem/platform.

I want to: 
- list various "products", or donation types that a user can select, customize and pay for
- be able to send/serve downloadable files to a donor, depending on their donation type 
- keep track of donors, donations and various custom bits of data the user enters
- add hooks to add donors to mailing lists, push donation notifications to social media, etc.

Basically, I want something that looks like a store and supports digital products, but processes donations instead of sales through PayPal.

Does anyone have experience using Spree (or something similar) to accept donations? I can't seem to find evidence that this works without a lot of hacking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this, but each will require you to roll up your sleeves and get into the code.  I would recommend, especially if you are learning rails, using Daniel Kehoe's "railsapp - Ruby on Rails Membership Site"

http://railsapps.github.com/rails-stripe-membership-saas/

It is a great tutorial and building block for what you are wanting to accomplish.  Don't just copy/clone it and use it out the box, I would run through the tutorial to get a better understanding of what is going on and how you can customize it to meet your needs.  It uses Stripe, for payment processing.